railway There is no active deployment for this service
I wanted to host my Node.js application on Railway, a platform that offers easy deployment for various types of applications. My application requires a connection to a MySQL database to function properly. To achieve this, I uploaded my GitHub repository containing the Node.js project to Railway, expecting the platform to automatically detect and deploy the application.
However, after the upload was complete, I encountered an issue. Railway displayed the message "There is no active deployment for this service," indicating that the deployment process had not started as expected. Despite the repository being uploaded successfully, the application did not start, and the deployment seemed to be stuck.
This issue is particularly frustrating because I need the application to be up and running on Railway, with a proper connection to the MySQL database. The build process should initiate automatically once the repository is uploaded, and the necessary environment variables and database configurations should be correctly set up. Unfortunately, this wasn't the case, and I need to figure out how to resolve this problem so that my Node.js app can be hosted successfully with a working database connection.

Could you [edit] your question and include a [mre]? Any relevant information from the Railway config or output would be helpful for the future readers.
